# Extracting information from a video game screenshot

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am trying to use image processing to detect and extract information such

- Attacker hero
- Victim hero

However my method is not that accurate and I could use some ideas to help make it better.

I have a screenshot of a killfeed from a game:

[image: I have a screenshot of a killfeed from a game:]

I use Emgu to perform a canny edge detection of the image:

```
 using (Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap))
        {
            //Convert the image to grayscale and filter out the noise
            using (Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp())
            {

                Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges = gray.Canny(40, 100);
                //Smooth out found edges
                cannyEdges._SmoothGaussian(3);
            }
        }
```

And get this result:

[image]

From the result I loop through the image to find a straight line with a width of 2 to then detect the border of the icon.

This however is really inaccurate as you can see the canny edged image has lines that I am not interested in, and the second icon does not even have a clear enough border for me to detect.

Is there any way better way to detect the icons?

Comment: I'd probably loop through the pixels as the killer has a blue border, the killed has a red border. Detect those colors and you'll be able to isolate the icons.

Comment: Do the character icons not appear in the same location in the killfeed each time?

Answer (score 0):

Before using hard algorithm like cannyEdge and other fft things, I would recommand to use common sense and eyes to :

- select a subset of the image you want to search In
- clean it

For instance, you may want to :

- filter on cyan color in order to detect the cyan square and/or cyan name (it also works with red).
- search for the white arrow that is always the same, then deduce where the squares are

Once it's clean, you'll have only the zone you want to process (for instance both squares with heroes). Then all kinds of algorythms you will use will be much more effective.

If the heroes pics always are the same you even may want to perform a simple difference between screen-zone and reference.

Comment: The background changes constantly though, so looking for the red and cyan colors would give me false positives. The color also changes depending on the users settings, so this would not be the most optimal approach for my case.

Comment: It really depends on image characteristics like the one you just gave, you have plenty of options : detect the arrow (if it's always visible) / detect perfectly vertical (or horizontal) monocolor lines using a vertical (horizontal) diffs / detect perfectly black zones (the background behind heroes) / detect higher contrasts (if the border color is always very different from background)  ... You have to "think" the visual obvious characteistics of your image.